# Import paths from folder using Vite with ReactJs and Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, package.json, esbuild

I have a big ReactJs project and wnat to migrate from react-scripts to viteJs after following the configurations, but seems I can't get it to work because I'm missing a concept or something
here is some of my project folder structure:

```
src/routes (as directory)
     |
     |-route_file1.js
     |-route_file2.js
     |-route_file3.js
     |-index.js

src/themes (as directory)
     |
     |-theme_file1.js
     |-theme_file2.js
     |-theme_file3.js
     |-index.js
```

I generally user below type of import method and it works fine in react-scripts compiler
react-scripts automatically select `index.js` file and no need to specify the `index.js` file name

App.js imports:

```
import Routes from 'routes';
import themes from 'themes';
```

i want to do the same in Vite, when i specify the directory name in import path, it goes directly to index.js file.

**Note**:if I change the imports like below it will be fixed but I dont want do this.

```
import Routes from './routes/index.js';
import themes from './themes/index.js';
```

**Update 01**

I Configure the vite like below :

```
//jsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

```
//vite.config.js

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
          src: "/src",
        },
      },
    optimizeDeps: {
        force: true,
        esbuildOptions: {
            loader: {
                '.js': 'jsx'
            },
        },
    }
})
```

now the file name is resolved but i shoud add './' from begining of imports !

```
// This is Ok in App.js 

import Routes from './routes';
import themes from './themes';
```

```
// This is NOT Ok in App.js 

import Routes from 'routes';
import themes from 'themes';
```

Answer (score 1):

In Vite, you can achieve the same behavior as you had with react by configuring your project to resolve imports from the index.js files in your directories. Vite uses a specific import alias configuration to achieve this.

How you can do it:

1. In your project's root directory, you should have a ***vite.config.js*** file. If you don't have it, create one.
2. Open ***vite.config.js*** and add the following code to configure import aliases:

```js
// vite.config.js
import path from 'path';

export default {
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        // This alias maps "routes" to the index.js file inside the "src/routes" directory
        find: /^routes$/,
        replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/routes/index.js')
      },
      {
        // This alias maps "themes" to the index.js file inside the "src/themes" directory
        find: /^themes$/,
        replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/themes/index.js')
      }
      // You can add more alias mappings for other directories if needed
    ]
  }
};
```

3. With this configuration, whenever you import ***routes or themes***, Vite will automatically resolve the import to the index.js file inside the respective directories.
4. You can now use your original import statements in your code:

```js
// App.js
import Routes from 'routes';
import themes from 'themes';
```

**this configuration will only work for import statements that exactly match the aliases you've set up.**
If you want to handle more complex imports or have additional directories to handle, you can add more alias mappings to the `vite.config.js` file.

By configuring import aliases in Vite, you can achieve a similar import behavior to what you had with react-scripts, without needing to specify the `index.js` file in your import paths.

Comment: I Updated the Question and now with Update-01 with configuration i by pass the index.js the current problem is about `./` character, More described in main quesion, would you please check it

Comment: sorry can u explain it better?